# lavaan: fix parameters of residual variance for multiple group confirmatory factor analysis

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I want to fix the parameter of a residual covariance to be zero for one gender group but not the other. But the following code doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
model<-'
f1=~x1 + x2 + x3
f2=~y1 + y2 + y3

x2 ~~ c(a1, 0)*x3
'
fit <-cfa(model, data=mydata, estimator="ML", missing="ML", group="gender")
summary(fit, fit.measures=T, standardized=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NA instead of a1.

```
model<-'
f1=~x1 + x2 + x3
f2=~y1 + y2 + y3

x2 ~~ c(NA, 0)*x3
'
fit <-cfa(model, data=mydata, estimator="ML", missing="ML", group="gender")
summary(fit, fit.measures=T, standardized=T)
```